# Deadlock on two different tables

Tags: sql-server, deadlock

I am facing deadlock issue and I can see that deadlock happened between two different tables.
Below is detailed scenario.

1. Delete query is trying take object lock on table test1
2. Another delete query is trying to page lock and that page id associated to table test2
3. At last delete query on test1 is selected as victim and it is terminated by SQL Server
4. Delete query on table test2 is executed fine

Here I am not able to understand how two non related transactions are involved in deadlock.
Please share your thoughts on this.

Deadlock Graph:
[Deadlock Graph link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfDSo.png)

Comment: can it be trigger on test2 which does something with test1?

Comment: If they were truly unrelated there wouldn't be a deadlock, so it's very likely you're misreading the situation. I'd start with posting the complete deadlock graph if you want more detailed feedback.

Comment: Hi Jeroen, Added deadlock graph for your reference.

Comment: We need the actual XDL (XML) graph, not an image of it. Please also show the queries involved, the relevant tables *and index* definitions, and please share the query plan via https://pastetheplan.com. Without this info it's impossible to properly diagnose a deadlock.

Comment: You are misreading this graph. Two process have IX locks on a page, which are compatible with each other. They are also trying to get an object IX lock on something which a third process has an X lock on it, therefore they block. That third process is also waiting on an IX for a different object, which a *fourth* process has an X lock on, that process in turn is waiting on a U lock for the original page. Possibly an early `SELECT` with `UPDLOCK` hint might help here, but hard to say without seeing the details I ask.